# sql server: update table random

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns of sample data. Column1 is the primary key and is tied with several other tables. Column 2 is an int that randomly ranges from 1 to 5. I'm looking for a way to change the data in place in column 2 so that it ranges from 1 to 8. I'm not an expert in SQL and I was wondering what would be the easiest way to do this. There are about 3400 records so I guess I could go in manually and type numbers at random but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `RAND()` function. Well, you could use it if it worked as someone would suppose.

This will **NOT** work in Sql-Server:

```
UPDATE tableT
  SET column2 = CAST(1 + (RAND() * 8) AS INT)
;
```

But this does:

```
UPDATE tableT
  SET column2 = 1 + 8 * RAND( CHECKSUM( NEWID() ) )
;
```

Comment: This will lead to `column2` in all 3400 rows having the same value in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

`rand()` is only evaluated once per query. So all your `column2` values will be the same.

For SQL Server 2008 you can use

```
UPDATE tableT
  SET column2 = 1+ (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) % 8)
```

For earlier versions

```
UPDATE tableT
  SET column2 = 1+ (abs(checksum(NewId())) % 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your answer would actually return NINE, right?

I'd try this instead

UPDATE tableT  SET column2 = CAST(1 + (RAND() * 7) AS INT);